# how to use \Udelcode for large Delimiter when using \big or \left or \right for STIXTwoMath OTF fonts?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math, math-fonts

I want to use OTF version of STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf, to get the large delimiter such as
`(),[],{ },|,/,\vert,\Vert,\langle,\rangle,\lceil,\rceil`, and so on, I need to modify what are all the delimiter, declared through `\DeclareMathDelimiter{}{}{}{}{}{}` in the `fontmath.ltx`

I redefined  through `\Udelcode ⟨char slot⟩ [=] ⟨fam.⟩ ⟨glyph slot⟩` command, i am getting the correct output for few delimiters only (),[],|

few of them are not rendered properly when using \big or \left, it is loading default LaTeX CMR fonts (CMEX10)

How to modify to get the proper font loading (OTF) for \left< . \right>, \langle,\rangle, \vert,\Vert,\lceil,\rceil,

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathsfont(Latin){STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathsfont(Digits){STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathsfont(Greek){STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathsfont(Symbols){STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}

\newfontface\StixMath{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[Scale=1.0,NFSSFamily=stix]
\DeclareSymbolFont{Stixsym}{TU}{stix}{m}{n}

%%% for Bracket
\Udelcode`\[\symStixsym"005B
\Udelcode`\]\symStixsym"005D

%%% for paranthesis
\Udelcode`\(\symStixsym"0028
\Udelcode`\)\symStixsym"0029

%%% for |
\Udelcode`\|\symStixsym"007C

\Udelcode`\<\symStixsym"3C
\Udelcode`\>\symStixsym"3E

\xdef\sqrt{\Uradical\symStixsym"221A}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ( )

$(01234567890)$

$\big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg(  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big) \Big) \bigg) \Bigg)$


$\displaystyle \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$\medskip

==========================\medskip

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% [ ]


$[01234567890]$

$\big[ \Big[ \bigg[ \Bigg[  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big] \Big] \bigg] \Bigg]$


$\displaystyle \left[ \frac{1}{2} \right]$\medskip


==========================\medskip
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% | |


$|01234567890|$

$\big| \Big| \bigg| \Bigg|  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big| \Big| \bigg| \Bigg|$


$\displaystyle \left| \frac{1}{2} \right|$


==========================\medskip


$<01234567890>$



$\big< \Big< \bigg< \Bigg<  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big> \Big> \bigg> \Bigg>$

$\displaystyle \left< \frac{1}{2} \right>$

=========

$\{01234567890\}$

$\big\{01234567890\big\}$

$\big\{01234567890\big\}$


$\big\{ \Big\{ \bigg\{ \Bigg\{  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\} \Big\} \bigg\} \Bigg\}$

$\displaystyle \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \right\}$

=========

$\sqrt{2}$

$\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\frac{1}{2}}}$


===================

$\displaystyle\big\vert \Big\vert \bigg\vert \Bigg\vert  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\vert \Big\vert \bigg\vert \Bigg\vert$

$\displaystyle\big\Vert \Big\Vert \bigg\Vert \Bigg\Vert  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\Vert \Big\Vert \bigg\Vert \Bigg\Vert$

$\displaystyle\big\langle \Big\langle \bigg\langle \Bigg\langle  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\rangle \Big\rangle \bigg\rangle \Bigg\rangle$

$\displaystyle\big\lceil \Big\lceil \bigg\lceil \Bigg\lceil  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\rceil \Big\rceil \bigg\rceil \Bigg\rceil$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not using `unicode-math`?

Comment: as egreg says `\usepackage{unicode-math}\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: note if you use `\bigg[` you lose the mathopen spacing, better to use `\biggl[` and `\biggr]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set mathcodes.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathsfont(Latin){STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathsfont(Digits){STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathsfont(Greek){STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathsfont(Symbols){STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}

\newfontface\StixMath{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[Scale=1.0,NFSSFamily=stix]
\DeclareSymbolFont{Stixsym}{TU}{stix}{m}{n}

%%% for bracket
\Umathcode`\[ = "4 \symStixsym "005B
\Umathcode`\] = "5 \symStixsym "005D
\Udelcode`\[ = \symStixsym "005B
\Udelcode`\] = \symStixsym "005D

%%% for parenthesis
\Umathcode`\( = "4 \symStixsym "0028
\Umathcode`\) = "5 \symStixsym "0029
\Udelcode`\( = \symStixsym"0028
\Udelcode`\) = \symStixsym"0029

%%% for |
\Umathcode`\| = "0 \symStixsym "007C
\Udelcode`\| = \symStixsym"007C
\def\vert{\Udelimiter "0 \symStixsym "007C }
\def\Vert{\Udelimiter "0 \symStixsym "2016 }

%%% for angle brackets
\def\langle{\Udelimiter "4 \symStixsym "27E8 }
\def\rangle{\Udelimiter "5 \symStixsym "27E9 }
\Udelcode`\<\symStixsym"27E8
\Udelcode`\>\symStixsym"27E9

%%% for braces
\def\lbrace{\Udelimiter "4 \symStixsym "007B }
\def\rbrace{\Udelimiter "5 \symStixsym "007D }

%%% floor
\def\lfloor{\Udelimiter "4 \symStixsym "230A }
\def\rfloor{\Udelimiter "4 \symStixsym "230B }

%% ceiling
\def\lceil{\Udelimiter "4 \symStixsym "2308 }
\def\rceil{\Udelimiter "4 \symStixsym "2309 }

\xdef\sqrt{\Uradical\symStixsym"221A }

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Parentheses}

$(01234567890)$

$\big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg(  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big) \Big) \bigg) \Bigg)$

$\displaystyle \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$

\subsection*{Brackets}

$[01234567890]$

$\big[ \Big[ \bigg[ \Bigg[  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big] \Big] \bigg] \Bigg]$

$\displaystyle \left[ \frac{1}{2} \right]$

\subsection*{Bars}

$|01234567890|$

$\big| \Big| \bigg| \Bigg|  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big| \Big| \bigg| \Bigg|$

$\displaystyle \left| \frac{1}{2} \right|$

\subsection*{Angle brackets}

$\langle 01234567890\rangle$

$\big< \Big< \bigg< \Bigg<  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big> \Big> \bigg> \Bigg>$

$\displaystyle \left< \frac{1}{2} \right>$

\subsection*{Braces}

$\{01234567890\}$

$\big\{ \Big\{ \bigg\{ \Bigg\{  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\} \Big\} \bigg\} \Bigg\}$

$\displaystyle \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \right\}$

\subsection*{Radical}

$\sqrt{2}$

$\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\frac{1}{2}}}$


\subsection*{Misc}

$\displaystyle\big\vert \Big\vert \bigg\vert \Bigg\vert  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\vert \Big\vert \bigg\vert \Bigg\vert$

$\displaystyle\big\Vert \Big\Vert \bigg\Vert \Bigg\Vert  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\Vert \Big\Vert \bigg\Vert \Bigg\Vert$

$\displaystyle\big\langle \Big\langle \bigg\langle \Bigg\langle  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\rangle \Big\rangle \bigg\rangle \Bigg\rangle$

$\displaystyle\big\lceil \Big\lceil \bigg\lceil \Bigg\lceil  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\rceil \Big\rceil \bigg\rceil \Bigg\rceil$

$\displaystyle\big\lfloor \Big\lfloor \bigg\lfloor \Bigg\lfloor  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \big\rfloor \Big\rfloor \bigg\rfloor \Bigg\rfloor$

\end{document}
```

After this, `pdffonts` shows

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
VNNHAY+STIXTwoText-Bold-Identity-H   CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
BELAGZ+STIXTwoMath-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      6  0
NQCIYR+STIXTwoText-Identity-H        CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  0
```

so no Computer Modern glyph is used.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is very helpful to me

Comment: the solution is working only on xelatex, it is not working in LuaLaTeX

Comment: @pdy_tam `mathspec` does not work with LuaLaTeX to begin with.

Comment: i used unicode-math.sty, my file main text is minion font, delimiters to be print from STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf, so i tried this solution, but not working

Comment: @pdy_tam This answer is *specific* for `mathspec`.